# Form will add a labels based on how many data are in the database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Good day guys.

I am doing a some kind of a advertisement app that will scroll texts.
I am currently doing it using label.top and timer function in C#.
It is doing quite good as I just use it for testing purposes. But the question I want to raise here is that, is it possible that C# will add labels for me automatically based on how many data I have in my database?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so. If you have N items from your DB that you want to display, you can dynamically create the labels as per below pseudocode:

```
//your code to retrieve data from database

for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
        l.Visible = true;
        l.Text = "Your text here";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(l);
    }
```

Note: The 'marquee' tag has been deprecated, and you should avoid using it where possible.